# Define model function parameters as a function of independent variable using lmfit python

Tags: python, lmfit

I'm trying to fit a model function to my data. the data is a time(t) series. the model function needs to change at specific times (in this case, t=7 and t=14) so that another expression is added to it at each time point. therefore i'd like to have a parameter that is a function of time, i.e. **c = 0 if t < 7 else 1**.

---

**rate()** is my model function, **a** and **k** are parameters that i'm trying to optimize and **c1**, **c2** are the above discussed time dependent coefficients. 
I used the *.make_params* method to define my parameters and passed the relevant expressions for **c1**, **c2**, into the *.add* method.

```
from numpy import exp
from lmfit import Model


# model function
def rate(x, a, k, c1, c2):
    def rate_unit(z):
        return a * (exp(-k * (z - 0.5)) - exp(-k * (z + 0.5)))

    return rate_unit(x) + c1 * rate_unit(x - 7) + c2 * rate_unit(x - 14)

# define independent and dependent variables
t = data.index.values
y = data.values

# setup the model
rate_model = Model(rate)

# setup parameters
parameters = rate_model.make_params()
parameters.add('a', value=200)
parameters.add('k', value=0.5)
parameters._asteval.symtable['t'] = t
parameters.add('c1', expr='0 if t < 7 else 1')
parameters.add('c2', expr='0 if t < 14 else 1')

# fit model to data
fit_result = rate_model.fit(y, parameters, x=t)
```

**data** is a pandas Series:

```
In [32]: data                                                                                                                                               
Out[32]: 
days
0      0.000000
1     50.986817
3      8.435668
7      0.519960
8     80.628749
10    10.067202
14     6.065180
15    88.029249
21     4.854688
Name: ORG, dtype: float64
```

this is the error i got:

```
ValueError
   <_ast.Module object at 0x7fab7d47f278>
The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model_dynamics.py", line 58, in <module>
    parameters.add('c1', expr='0 if t < 7 else 1')

ValueError: at expr='<_ast.Module object at 0x7fab7d47f278>'
```

I'd be grateful for any advice,

cheers,

Comment: This (common) error suggest that you are comparing multiple values (array) with just one value (boolean), which is ambiguous as it says. Dependeing on what you want, you can use  a.any() or a.all() to make the comparison. You probably want to compare a specific time instant with your threshold

Comment: maybe change `expr='0 if t < 7 else 1'` this line to `expr='1*(t>=7)'` ?

Comment: Thanks @BlueRineS. I tried <pre>expr='1*(t>=7)'<code>, but got the same error   ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.

Comment: can you show an example of what `data` is supposed to be? It would be easier for us to help that way.

Comment: I edited the question and added what data looks like @BlueRineS

Comment: Ill have a look at it.

Comment: `expr='1*(t>=7).any()'` and `expr='1*(t>=14).any()'` does work but Im not sure if that's what you want..

Comment: this 'expr='1*(t>=7).any()'' actually works , but it just sets **c1**  equal to 1. what i need is an expression that evaluates to 0 as long as t<7 and 1 when t>=7.  thanks again @BlueRineS

Comment: can you include your `t` time variable in your `rate` model somehow? Because then we could make it work

Comment: I'm not sure i understand. in the model x represents the time variable(independent variable). i guess u don't mean replace the character x with t?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters in `lmfit` are meant to contain a single value.  They will be evaluated once per fitting step (that is, per call to your objective/model function) and will not be evaluated separately for each data point.

Anyway, what you would want to use is "numpy.where()" in place of the comparison operator.

But, I think it would be more obvious and reable to just do that "where" in the code, not in parameter expressions, such as with:

```
import numpy as np
# model function
def rate(x, a, k):
    def rate_unit(z):
        return a * (np.exp(-k * (z - 0.5)) - enp.xp(-k * (z + 0.5)))
    c1 = np.zeros(len(x))
    c2 = np.zeros(len(x))
    c1[np.where(x>7)] = 1
    c2[np.where(x>14)] = 1
    return rate_unit(x) + c1 * rate_unit(x-7) + c2 * rate_unit(x-14)


# setup the model
rate_model = Model(rate)

# setup parameters
parameters = rate_model.make_params(a=200, k=0.5)

# fit model to data
fit_result = rate_model.fit(y, parameters, x=t)
```

It is probably more efficient and closer to what you were doing to compute `c1` and `c2` once ahead of time.  You can then tell lmfit to treat these as independent, non-varying parameters:

```
import numpy as np
# helper function (define once, not each time `rate` is called!)
def rate_unit(z):
    return a * (np.exp(-k * (z - 0.5)) - enp.xp(-k * (z + 0.5)))

# model function
def rate(x, a, k, c1, c2):
    return rate_unit(x) + c1 * rate_unit(x-7) + c2 * rate_unit(x-14)

# setup the model
rate_model = Model(rate, independent_vars=('x', 'c1', 'c2'))

# setup parameters
parameters = rate_model.make_params(a=200, k=0.5)

c1 = np.zeros(len(t))
c2 = np.zeros(len(t))
c1[np.where(t>7)] = 1
c2[np.where(t>14)] = 1
# fit model to data
fit_result = rate_model.fit(y, parameters, x=t, c1=c1, c2=c2)
```

Of course, the results should be the same.